# Powering the output side of a voltage regulator?

Tags: power, voltage, voltage-regulator, output

Would powering the output side of a voltage regulator cause any damage to it? (The ground pin would be attached as well) It will not be normally, but I am making a multi-voltage power converter and would like to know if doing such would cause any damage. The regulator would not be the only way for electricity to pass through the circuit, but would be a way. Looking at the schematics, I don't think so, but would like to clarify if there would be an issue.

Comment: Sometimes, it's okay to power the output side of the regulator.  Sometimes not.  It depends on the particular regulator.  Post the model of the voltage regulator, or - better yet - a link to the datasheet.  Ideally, post a snippet of the schematic.  While you don't have enough reputation to post inline images, you can upload the photo to some 3rd party image hosting site (e.g. flicker, picasa, etc), then edit your post and add a link to that photo. Somebody with enough reputation will edit your post and inline the photo.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, yes. It will damage the regulator. In some cases, regulators include protection to avoid this. This is generally found only in a few LDOs and should not be assumed unless the datasheet explicitly says so. This protection is in the form of a reverse biased diode, pointing from output to input.  When you power only the output, the diode conducts and sends it along to the input as well. Note that even in the presence of the diode, if you plan on doing it regularly and not just as an accident, additional care must be taken. Most LDOs with reverse diode protection specify maximum time and voltage that it can sustain. If you need more, make sure to include a decent power diode as well (the 4007 works for most cases)